# Replace characters in string

Tags: java

I need to replace values in a string:

```
public static String replaceVals(String str) {
  String[] array = str.split("");
  String newStr = "";
  for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    newStr += (array[i] == "T") ? "F" : "T";
  }
  return newStr;
}
```

Failed results:

```
input:           "TFF"
expected output: "FTT"
actual output:   "FFF"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: you can use char type and `toCharArray` method

Comment: `array[i].equals("T")`...not `==`. Use `equals` for comparing `Objects` `==` for comparing primitives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just convert your given String to a char array, modify the array, and return a new String using the modified char array.

```
public static String replaceVals(String str) {
    String[] array = str.toCharArray();
    for (int i=0; i<array.length;i++) {
        array[i] = array[i] == 'T' ? 'F' : 'T';
    }
    return new String(array);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use `.equals` instead of `==`

== checks for the reference where as.equals checks for value

```
public static String replaceVals(String str) {
  String[] array = str.split("");
  String newStr = "";
  for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    newStr += (array[i].equals( "T")) ? "F" : "T";
  }
  return newStr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use == when comparing chars so instead of splitting into an array of Strings you can use `String.toCharArray` to get an array of Characters.  Then when you compare you need to use the single quote to create a char.

```
public static String replaceVals(String str) {
    char[] array = str.toCharArray();
    String newStr = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      newStr += (array[i] == 'T') ? "F" : "T";
    }
    return newStr;
}
```